# $z\exp(z)$ surjectivity with the Little Picard Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I would like to prove the surjectivity of this function :

\begin{align*} 
f\colon\mathbb{C}&\to\mathbb{C}\\
z&\mapsto z\exp(z)
\end{align*}

You can use the **Little Picard Theorem**: If a function $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is entire and non-constant, then the set of values that $f(z)$ assumes is either the whole complex plane or the plane minus a single point.

Thanks.

Comment: Why cannot be the case 'plane minus a single point' for $f$?

Comment: While the little picard theorem is nice, it is a bit strong for this problem and a related one:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308758/is-z-1ez-1-surjective/2308787#2308787

The better thing to use is finite growth

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $w$ is not in the image of $f$. Since $f(z) - w$ is entire and never zero, it can be written as $f(z) - w = \exp(g(z))$ for some entire function $g$. Notice that $f(z) - w = -w$ only when $z = 0$. Apply the little Picard theorem to to $g(z)$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: what other value does $e^g$ miss?

Comment: @TheSubstitute Suppose $-w = \exp(g(w'))$. Then $g$ misses almost all of $g(w') + n(2\pi i)$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Because if $g$ take such values then $f$ will be zero at those points, but f is zero only at zero. Right?