# Is $z^{-1}(e^z-1)$ surjective?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is the entire function

$$
   f(z)=\frac{1}{z}(e^z-1)
$$
surjective?

I tried to argue like in the question below, but it does not seem to work in a similar way.

[$z\exp(z)$ surjectivity with the Little Picard Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606547/z-expz-surjectivity-with-the-little-picard-theorem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Little Picard Theorem is a bit strong for this problem and the one you linked to. The good thing about these two problems is that the functions involved are of finite growth. Here, $f$ has order $1$.

If $w \not \in im(f)$ for some $w \in \mathbb{C}$, then $f(z)-w$ is an entire function of order $1$ with no zeroes. Therefore, Hadamard's factorization theorem implies $f(z)-w = e^{az+b}$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. This yields $e^z-1-zw = ze^{az+b}$ for all $z \not = 0$. This doesn't look possible. I'll let you finish from here.

Comment: Very clear. I understand that Picard is too strong, but is there a way to use it, similar as in the linked question? Thanks!

Comment: Well it would be hard for me to say no to that question! But I did think about it for a bit and couldn't see how to use Picard here. The only way I could see how to use it would be as in the question you linked to...

Answer (score 5):

Since $f(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z}$ is entire and non-constant, by [Little Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) it is either surjective or just misses a single complex value. Let us assume to be in the second case. The missing value has to be a real value by Schwarz' reflection principle, since $f$ is real over the real line (assuming that $f$ misses some $w\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, it also misses $\overline{w}$). The missing value is not zero since $f(2\pi i)=0$. The missing value is not some $\alpha>1$ since the line $y=1+\alpha z$ meets the graph of $g(z)=e^z$ at some point with a positive abscissa by the convexity of $g(z)$. The missing value is not some $\alpha\in(0,1)$ since the line $y=1+\alpha z$ meets the graph of $g(z)=e^z$ at some point with a negative abscissa by the convexity of $g(z)$. Negative values are also attained, hence it follows that the only missing value can be $1$, but $1=f(0)$, so $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Why are negative values also attained? It does not seem to be the same as for positive $\alpha$. For positive $\alpha$ the values of $z$ that give equality are actually real, but for negative $\alpha$, if it is attained, the values of $z$ must be non-real. Is there a simple reason  why  all negative values are there as well?

Comment: @Markus: $g(z)=e^z+\alpha z-1$ is surjective as well for any $\alpha>0$. Such a function is entire, non constant and assuming is misses $\beta$ it misses $\beta+2\pi i\alpha$ too. Since there is at most one exceptional value, $g(z)$ is surjective and $g(z)=0$ has a solution.

Comment: I see. But this argument works for any non-zero $\alpha$, real or complex, doesn't it?  Clearly $0$ is also attained, so the entire proof could have been just your comment, right?

Comment: @Markus: indeed, you are right.

Comment: Could one use the intermediate value theorem for showing all the real values are attained?